# Can you take hand crossbows as beginning weapons as a fighter or paladin?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, fighter, paladin

When you take the fighter or paladin as your starting class, you get the equipment options of "*(a) a martial weapon and a shield or (b) two martial weapons*"

hand and heavy crossbows are considered "martial ***ranged*** weapons". Does this then mean that a fighter or paladin can choose to take two hand crossbows as their beginning equipment, or does the semantics of them being considered ranged weapons make this invalid.

Answer (score 11):

### You can take two hand or heavy crossbows

Hand Crossbows and Heavy Crossbows are martial weapons. The equipment bullet does not dictate that you need to pick martial **melee** weapons, so any martial weapon will do. P. 146, *PHB*:

> The two categories are **simple** and **martial**. Most people can
> use simple weapons with proficiency. These weapons
> include clubs, maces, and other weapons often found in
> the hands of commoners. Martial weapons, including
> swords, axes, and polearms, require more specialized
> training to use effectively.